# Linux UCD-SNMP-MIB no response

Tags: snmp, linux

I install snmpd, snmp and snmp-mibs-downloader package on my debian jessie.

Some mib's on my linux Responded but UCD-SNMP-MIB in not responded.

e.g:

```
root@MRT:/etc/snmp# snmpwalk -v1 -c public localhost DISMAN-EVENT- MIB::sysUpTimeInstance
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (458675) 1:16:26.75
root@MRT:/etc/snmp#
```

But this is no responsed:

e.g 1:

```
root@MRT:/etc/snmp# snmpwalk -v1 -c public localhost UCD-SNMP-MIB::ucdavis
End of MIB
root@MRT:/etc/snmp#
```

e.g 2:

```
root@MRT:/etc/snmp#  snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
root@MRT:/etc/snmp#
```

and My snmp config file:

/etc/snmp/snmpd.config

```
    ###############################################################################
#
# EXAMPLE.conf:
#   An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP agent ('snmpd')
#   See the 'snmpd.conf(5)' man page for details
#
#  Some entries are deliberately commented out, and will need to be explicitly activated
#
###############################################################################
#
#  AGENT BEHAVIOUR
#

#  Listen for connections from the local system only
#agentAddress  udp:172.16.98.24:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161



###############################################################################
#
#  SNMPv3 AUTHENTICATION
#
#  Note that these particular settings don't actually belong here.
#  They should be copied to the file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf
#     and the passwords changed, before being uncommented in that file *only*.
#  Then restart the agent

#  createUser authOnlyUser  MD5 "remember to change this password"
#  createUser authPrivUser  SHA "remember to change this one too"  DES
#  createUser internalUser  MD5 "this is only ever used internally, but still change the password"

#  If you also change the usernames (which might be sensible),
#  then remember to update the other occurances in this example config file to match.



###############################################################################
#
#  ACCESS CONTROL
#

                                                 #  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                             #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly

                                             #  Full access from an example network
                                             #     Adjust this network address to match your local
                                             #     settings, change the community string,
                                             #     and check the 'agentAddress' setting above
#rocommunity public  
#rocommunity public  Meta.local
                                             #  Full read-only access for SNMPv3
 rouser   authOnlyUser
                                                 #  Full write access for encrypted requests
                                                 #     Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
#rwuser   authPrivUser   priv

#  It's no longer typically necessary to use the full 'com2sec/group/access' configuration
#  r[ow]user and r[ow]community, together with suitable views, should cover most requirements



###############################################################################
#
#  SYSTEM INFORMATION
#

#  Note that setting these values here, results in the corresponding MIB objects being 'read-only'
#  See snmpd.conf(5) for more details
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
                                                 # Application + End-to-End layers
sysServices    72


#
#  Process Monitoring
#
                               # At least one  'mountd' process
proc  mountd
                               # No more than 4 'ntalkd' processes - 0 is OK
proc  ntalkd    4
                           # At least one 'sendmail' process, but no more than 10
proc  sendmail 10 1

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "proc" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  Disk Monitoring
#
                           # 10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "disk" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  System Load
#
                               # Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages
load   12 10 5

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::laTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table *will* be populated, even without a "load" entry in the snmpd.conf file



###############################################################################
#
#  ACTIVE MONITORING
#

                                #   send SNMPv1  traps
 trapsink     localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c traps
#trap2sink    localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c INFORMs
#informsink   localhost public

#  Note that you typically only want *one* of these three lines
#  Uncommenting two (or all three) will result in multiple copies of each notification.


#
#  Event MIB - automatically generate alerts
#
                                   # Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
iquerySecName   internalUser       
rouser          internalUser
                                   # generate traps on UCD error conditions
defaultMonitors          yes
                                   # generate traps on linkUp/Down
linkUpDownNotifications  yes



###############################################################################
#
#  EXTENDING THE AGENT
#

#
#  Arbitrary extension commands
#
 extend    test1   /bin/echo  Hello, world!
 extend-sh test2   echo Hello, world! ; echo Hi there ; exit 35
#extend-sh test3   /bin/sh /tmp/shtest

#  Note that this last entry requires the script '/tmp/shtest' to be created first,
#    containing the same three shell commands, before the line is uncommented

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB tables (nsExtendConfigTable, nsExtendOutput1Table
#     and nsExtendOutput2Table) to see the resulting output

#  Note that the "extend" directive supercedes the previous "exec" and "sh" directives
#  However, walking the UCD-SNMP-MIB::extTable should still returns the same output,
#     as well as the fuller results in the above tables.

    
#
#  "Pass-through" MIB extension command
#
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /bin/sh       PREFIX/local/passtest
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /usr/bin/perl PREFIX/local/passtest.pl

# Note that this requires one of the two 'passtest' scripts to be installed first,
#    before the appropriate line is uncommented.
# These scripts can be found in the 'local' directory of the source distribution,
#     and are not installed automatically.

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB::netSnmpPassExamples subtree to see the resulting output


#
#  AgentX Sub-agents
#
                                           #  Run as an AgentX master agent
 master          agentx
                                           #  Listen for network connections (from localhost)
                                           #    rather than the default named socket /var/agentx/master
#agentXSocket    tcp:localhost:705
```

/etc/snmp/snmp.config

```
#  Listen for connections from the local system only
#agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
#agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
```

Where is wrong?!

## tnx

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [unix.se] or [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read correctly your SNMPd config, you allow your `"public" community` to read only the OID contained in the group `systemonly`.

```
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                             #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly
```

It works with `MIB::sysUpTimeInstance` because this OID is contained in the system MIB: `(iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) system(1) sysUpTime(3) sysUpTimeInstance(0))` which correspond with the systemonly ACL.

If you want to read the UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal (OID:  .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6) which is contained in the private MIB, you must add this OID to the group `systemonly`. Add this line :

```
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021
```

With this line you will allow the `public community` to read all the private MIB.

Comment: great! this answer was right ? it has helped you ?

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer for my problem, Thanks again.